# Ant set platforms.JDK_1.6.home without parameter

Tags: windows, ant, properties, java, java-home

I'm having a problem trying to run ant on a windows machine. I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\USER\testing\mercurial\project\NetbeansProject\nbproject\build-impl.xml:111: The J2SE Platform is not correctly set up.
 Your active platform is: JDK_1.6, but the corresponding property "platforms.JDK_1.6.home" is not found in the project's properties files.
 Either open the project in the IDE and setup the Platform with the same name or add it manually.
 For example like this:
     ant -Duser.properties.file=<path_to_property_file> jar (where you put the property "platforms.JDK_1.6.home" in a .properties file)
  or ant -Dplatforms.JDK_1.6.home=<path_to_JDK_home> jar (where no properties file is used)
```

If I execute `ant -Dplatforms.JDK_1.6.home=%JAVA_HOME%` it executes fine, but, is there some way to avoid adding this parameter every time I need to build a program?

Comment: have you tried adding `<property name="platforms.JDK_1.6.home" value="${env.JAVA_HOME}" />` before invocation?

Comment: @Alex Where should I add that property? I only need to resolve this problem on one computer, so I cannot modify the build file.
Is there some way to define this property system wide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to set `ant` properties outside of command line or properties files loaded explicitly by the build script.

If you are looking for a less verbose way to launch `ant`, try using either a wrapper `.bat` file, or assigning an alias `doskey ant=ant "-Dplatforms.JDK_1.6.home=%JAVA_HOME%"`